# How do I use ctags functionality in vim with cscope installed?

Tags: vim, c, ctags

When I install `cscope` by adding the line `Bundle 'chazy/cscope_maps` to my `.vimrc` file, my tags menu (`g+[`) is replaced with a cscope list, which seems to contain a list of files where the tag is *called*, not where it is *declared*. I would like to be able to use cscope using `CTRL\+s` to get a list of locations where the tag is referenced, and then use `g+[` to get locations where the object is declared.

Can I do this? I'm not fussed whether I'm using `cscope` or `ctags` to get the token declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled across your question while having the same problem and I've found a solution.

I assume that, you as well as I installed cscope_maps.vim in your .vim/ directory. When you inspect the file exactly it has a flag "cscopetag" that basically combines ctags and cscope. Removing this flag will disable <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> binding for cscope and only ctags remains.

- Use both cscope and ctags for <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>, `:ta`, and `vim -t`.
- Comment out the flag like this: `" set cscopetag`.

Answer (score 1):

Run `:set nocscopetag`

You can add this setting to your .vimrc to make it persistent.